# Laravel Forge Deployment environment variable issue

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-forge

My App will not deploy because it is missing required environment variables.

When I set these from within Forge, they appear. As soon as I hit deploy they all disappear, then my deploy fails.

I am using Symfony2 with Digital Ocean - but shouldn't make a difference, the issue is all environment variables get deleted prior to a deploy. That can't be right?

Here is the error message from Symfony, but it is due to the environment variable not being set (in forge I can see it get deleted right before a deploy)

```
 - Installing tedivm/stash-bundle (v0.4.2)
Loading from cache

 - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
Loading from cache

Generating autoload files
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/AppKernel.php on line 31
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/console:27
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2343
PHP   6. AppKernel->registerBundles() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2513

Fatal error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/AppKernel.php on line 31

Call Stack:
    0.0002     225112   1. {main}() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/console:0
    0.0253    3126784   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/console:27
    0.0279    3329440   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
    0.0279    3329664   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
    0.0279    3329960   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2343
    0.0279    3330560   6. AppKernel->registerBundles() /home/forge/beta.dashboardhub.io/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2513

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Sure, I will add it above now, but the reason why I didn't add it was because, it is a symfony error & distracts from the issue - which is environment variables seem to get deleted prior to a deploy

Comment: What `composer.phar` command did you used? Please add it in your answer, this is as important as the output of the command.

Comment: I didn't use any, Forge manages it. But I am guessing it is with `--no-dev`

Comment: Yes `SensioGeneratorBundle` is declared in the `dev` part of `composer.json`, so if you need it you should remove the `--no-dev` option.

Comment: I don't need it. I set the environment variables in Forge before I deploy for symfony to run in prod mode, but as soon as I hit deploy they get deleted, hence this issue with mixed modes, where composer runs in prod (eg. no dev) but symfony is running in dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue / feature of Forge. It does reset the environment variables before a deploy.

Here is the response from their support...

> Yeah that has been a point of confusion I will fix today. Basically
>   the original thought was if you are installing a new project you will
>   want new environment variables, but many people set the environment
>   variables before installing.
>
> Taylor Otwell

So it looks like it will be fixed soon.

I have not been able to find a Forge Ticket, Twitter Account or Deployment changelog to follow this progress.

---

**Temporary Solution / Work around**

> No there is not currently a deployment change log. I will let you know
>   when it is ready to go. It’s a little trickier than it sounds… for
>   now, you could install the project and just un-check the “Install
>   Composer” step, then add your environment variables, then click the
>   “Deploy” button so it picks up the composer install step.
>
> Taylor Otwell

Comment: Still appears to be an issue (May 2020)