# Laravel Forge, suddenly env is empty

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I've deployed a Laravel app on Digitalocean using Laravel Forge. Site runs fine for a day or two, then suddenly the `.env` file gets wiped, all variables deleted and file is 0 bytes.

`php artisan env` returns
`Current application environment: production`

But the file itself is empty. Owner is `forge` and chmod is 755

I've tried running `php artisan config:cache` but from time to time the .env file suddenly is completely blank, turning my app to become unavailable of course.

Digitalocean runs nginx.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: Are there any console commands scheduled to run around the time that it happens? Does it happen after you deploy, or is it truly random? Are there any requests in your access log that look suspicious? Does the file get deleted, or does it still exist but with no contents -- implying a process is writing to it, instead of deleting it?

Comment: There is a nightly scheduler, in my Forge scheduler: /usr/local/bin/composer self-update

But the latest incident happened when I visited the site (probably running a cached version), did a force refresh and .env is edited to an empty file at the same time I did the refresh

The files still exists, it is just empty.

Comment: UPDATE: I now see that immideately after uploading .env file with a bunch of variables, it gets emptied after a few seconds.

I'm now trying this: config:clear -> uploading .env file -> config:cache to see if it helps

Comment: This is atypical behaviour, there's no reason your `.env` should ever be modified by your application, or Laravel itself. Are you sure you haven't added any code that could be doing this?

Comment: To be honest I am just using a starter template. I can ask the author.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the starter template so that I can review the code?

Comment: Here is my instance of it: https://github.com/filipblaauw/fiskelogg-v2
Original template is purchased via Scriptmint, so I don't have a clean repo-link for that.

But I think the .env gets wiped when I store the configuration from the admin part of the app (POST request to /api/configuration)

Comment: The issue appears to be that the ConfigurationRepository is calling the `envu` helper (found in `app/Helper/helper.php`) which writes to the `.env` file. So, presumably, there's a bug in that method causing it to write nothing. Looking at `ConfigurationController` I can see in the `store` method that it's setting the contents of `.env` based on the request input, are you sure that the configuration values are being passed? https://github.com/filipblaauw/fiskelogg-v2/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ConfigurationController.php#L54 I'd recommend talking to the script developer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will ask the developer. I also noticed that in the included .env file from the template, APP_ENV it set to local, not to production which is what I am using in my .env. Not sure if it will make a difference.

Comment: dd($this->repo->create($this->request->all())); returns null

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519832 I followed Taylor Otwell's workaround to deploy without installing Composer dependencies. I added my environment variables afterward and it worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Forge Deployment environment variable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512315/laravel-forge-deployment-environment-variable-issue)